# Inserting values in table from same table with one column modified

Tags: sql, db2, sql-insert

I have a situation where I want to insert the values in a table by using existing column values but with one date column modified. I can try to insert the values with select statement from the table, but how do I add different value for the date column?

Comment: you'll need to be a bit more specific. What database are you using, what is the table definition and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Its a DB2 table, with columns like "SA1" "SA2" "date" "other columns".I want to insert the values which are existing for a specific date, but with a different date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample: *(this copies another record but sets the date to another explicit value)*

```
INSERT [table] (col1, col2, col3, datecol, othercol)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, '20130104', othercol
  FROM [table]
 WHERE pk_id = 4;
```

Comment: if 20130104 is not existing in table will it work with select statement, thats what I was confused about

Comment: Yes it will work. The formatting of date literals in db2 may be different though... but you get the point.